# fputcsv is putting duplicate values in my file

Tags: php, csv

I have read all topics about problem which was described at `stackoverflow` linked to problem of duplicated values in `fputcsv` function. Unfortunately I am using `PDO` and `psql` (presented solutions was described using simple `mysql` connectors)

But first I will describe my problem showing some code. Here is what I put:

```
$db=ConnectionFactory::CreateConnection();

$fileName = 'somefile.csv';

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");


    $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );


    $query = "SELECT * FROM person";
    $results = $db->query($q)->fetchall();

    $headerDisplayed = false;

    foreach ( $results as $data ) {
        // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
        if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
            // Use the keys from $data as the titles
            fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));
            $headerDisplayed = true;
        }

        // Put the data into the stream
        fputcsv($fh, $data);
    }
    // Close the file
    fclose($fh);
    // Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
    exit;
```

`CSV` file I am getting contains double values, for example:

```
"name","name","phone","phone","email","email"
"John","John","501231","501231","test","test"
"Bob","Bob","1111","1111","test2","test2"
```

When I am trying to execute function `pg_fetch_array` I am getting error:

```
pg_fetch_array() expect parameter 1 to be resource, array given
```

What can I do to fix my csv?

Comment: `fputcsv` is working pretty fine and does not lead to duplicate columns. I guess the error must be in the results array already. Have you debugged the database result to make that sure?

Comment: Look at the contents of $data before you send it to `fputcsv()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default for a PDO fetch() or fetchall() is PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, which is to retrieve the row as both enumerated and associative array, so you will get duplication

Fetch as either enumerated, or as associative, but don't simply default it

```
$db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so easy and I did not find it on my own. Thank you Mark!

Comment: Didn't realise I needed to add PDO::FETCH_ASSOC